# Keyboard shortcut to switch to a specific window

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 23.10

Is there a way to specify a keyboard shortcut to switch to a specific window? I know about Alt+Tab, Alt+`, Alt+Esc etc. But all of those keys cycle through all windows, which is not what I'm looking for. I would like a key that takes me straight to a specific window, irrespective of which window is currently in focus.

My use case is that I use Google Meet for meetings while also looking at other windows (slides, web pages, code editors, Slack). I'm muted most of the time, and when I want to talk, I can press the space bar to temporarily unmute myself ("push-to-talk" feature). But that only works when I'm in the Google Meet window. So what I'm looking for is a key that I press, followed by the space bar, so that I can quickly start talking on Google Meet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu settings for keyboard shortcuts you can creat `Custom Shortcuts` which execute a command.

So if you can find a terminal program to do what you want it should be easy to write a shell script and toggle it to a keyboard shortcut.

I use `wmctrl` to do this which offers various options to interact with X window manager so at a very basic level I can focus a window based on it's title such as `/usr/bin/wmctrl -a "Firefox"`

However, I use Xorg/X11 so if you use Wayland instead which is the current default then `wmctrl` probably won't work. I never use Wayland so can't say if there are alternative programs but you may be able to find something.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising! I also use Xorg. There are still too many apps that don't work properly with Wayland.

Comment: FYI `xdotool` is another good command line tool for managing windows.